# How to use ajax load more wordpress plugin with attachment post type

Tags: ajax, wordpress

I've use ajax load more before and it worked great. In my newest project, I need to use load more button on the gallery of images. But it seems that ajax load more plugin cannot handle attachment post type. Any help or suggestion guys?

Comment: which plugin did you use?

Comment: @OwaisAlam I use this https://id.wordpress.org/plugins/ajax-load-more/

Comment: @OwaisAlam any help ?

Comment: Did you call this in your custom post type? Actually i have read the documentation of the plugin you have to define the post type in which you call the ajax_load_more. You have to pass the 'slug' of your post type in it.

Comment: @OwaisAlam I did this `[ajax_load_more post_type="attachment" posts_per_page="4"]` and failed, if I replace attachment with other post type such as post, page, or any custom post then it worked well

Answer (score 0):

Use following shortcode for load more images.

```
[ajax_load_more repeater="template_22" posts_per_page="4" transition="fade" images_loaded="true" css_classes="images-loaded"]
```

For more information, please check [link](https://connekthq.com/plugins/ajax-load-more/examples/images-loaded/)

Comment: sorry but I've tried to use above code but I still can't get it to work. I also try  [ajax_load_more post_type="attachment" posts_per_page="4"] but still no luck

Answer (score 0):

I recently had the same issue, it is to do with 'post_status' field. Attachment files have a post_status of 'inherit' and not 'published'. 'published' is the default post_status if you don't define one in your shortcode.

You have to include it in the 'custom_args' parameter in ajax load more.

Hope that helps.